# Learner's permit to practice before driving test - over 18

Tags: usa, immigration, driving-license

I have a UK driving license and need to get a new one in Florida.
According to the law I can't use the UK driving license anymore because 30 days passed since I moved to the US.

Can adults (+18) get a learner's permit to practice before the driving test? I would like to do so for about a week before the actual test.

[I read around](https://www.firsttimedriver.com/florida/learners-permit.aspx) that the learner's permit is only for non-adults, is that correct?
Or is it given to me automatically (for free?) when I pass the written test?

Thanks

Comment: You moved to the US, but when did you actually become a [resident of Florida](https://www.flhsmv.gov/driver-licenses-id-cards/visiting-florida-faqs/)?

Comment: Interesting!! According to those instructions I am not yet. Thanks!

Comment: Double check dmv.org because that's not the official site for a dmv. They're mining the data.

Answer (score 3):

> Can adults (+18) get a learner's permit to practice before the driving test?

Yes.

> I read around that the learner's permit is only for non-adults, is that correct?

No.  Nothing on the page you linked to says that.  It lists a minimum age, and notes that if you are under 18 you need your parents' permission.  This implies that those over 18 can also get a learner's permit.

Comment: As you noted it lists parent consent, then also allowed hours for driving, 50 hours of driving experience to take the driving test, etc etc so it's not really helpful or solves my doubts.  "Is it given to me automatically when I pass the written test?"
According to this article I assume that's a yes - dmv.org/fl-florida/drivers-permits.php "Cash or a check for $48 for the Class E driver's license fee, which also includes a learner license."

Comment: Just called one of the the driving test places near where I live and they confirmed that it's given for free when you pass the written test

Comment: @GaSacchi that's the normal state of affairs in the US, but I did not mention it in the answer because I have no experience with Florida.  If I recall correctly, in New York it's allowed to drive with a foreign license and a New York learner's permit, but I am not certain, and I have no idea whether that would also be true in Florida.

Comment: Since you mentioned you're from NY maybe you can help with a related question. I will eventually move to NY and I read around ( https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/exchange-out-state-driver-license ) that
I can't convert a Florida license to a NY one if I hadn't have it for at least 6 months. At the same time though I'm obliged to convert it within 30 days from my arrival in NY. That's confusing. Should I just wait the 6 months since I will not actually use it in NY? Thanks

Comment: @GaSacchi As you seem to suspect, the 30 day limit is only significant if you're actually driving.  I would probably wait the six months if I didn't intend to drive.  The only other option would be to get a license "from scratch"; that is, to take the written test in New York, get a learner's permit, and take the road test.

Comment: Actually it's 30 days after becoming a NY resident and to be considered a resident you have to live in NY for one year. 
"How long does it take to get residency in NYC?
To qualify as a New York State resident, you must have established legal residence by maintaining a domicile in New York State for a period of at least one year" - http://www.fitnyc.edu/recently-accepted-students/establish-residency.php

Comment: Update: it's actually 90 days to be considered a NY resident as stated in note 1 here https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/exchange-out-state-driver-license

Comment: @GaSacchi residency for the purpose of state university tuition is not particularly relevant to residency for driver licensing, and vice versa.  The 90-day rule is that a *presumption* exists, but it is rebuttable before a judge: if you maintain a residence elsewhere but spend six months in New York, a judge could still find that you are not required to get a NYS license. And if you never drive in New York, you would never need a NYS license.